# How to calculate the difference between rows compared to another specific row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
full_name  x
q          1.5
q_1        1.3
q_2        1.2
q_3        1.3
r          1.5
r_1        1.3
r_2        1.2
r_3        1.3
```

and I'd like to create a new column which is the difference between the suffixed full names and their bases, such as the following:

```
full_name  x    x_diff
q          1.5  0
q_1        1.3  -0.2
q_2        1.2  -0.3
q_3        1.3  -0.2
r          1.5  0
r_1        1.3  -0.2
r_2        1.2  -0.3
r_3        1.3  -0.2
```

so, `q` - `q`, `q_1` - `q`, `q_2` - `q`, `q_3` - `q`, and the same for `r`.

I've tried something like `df['x_diff'] = df.res - df[df.main_name == df.full_name].x` but that doesn't work. Any advice on what to do?

Comment: could you be more specific, for me the idea of this substraction is still not clear?

Comment: Why are they negative? They should be positive.  I think you just want `df['x'] - df.groupby('main_name')['x'].transform('first')` if your frame is sorted like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Series` for matched `main_name` with `full_name` with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then subtract [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)ed `main_name`:

```
s =  df.loc[df.main_name == df.full_name].set_index('main_name')['x']

df['x_diff'] = df.x - df.main_name.map(s)
print (df)
  full_name main_name    x  x_diff
0         q         q  1.5     0.0
1       q_1         q  1.3    -0.2
2       q_2         q  1.2    -0.3
3       q_3         q  1.3    -0.2
4         r         r  1.5     0.0
5       r_1         r  1.3    -0.2
6       r_2         r  1.2    -0.3
7       r_3         r  1.3    -0.2
```

If always first values are equals in `main_name` with `full_name` per groups subtract `Series` created by [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['x_diff'] = df.x - df.groupby('main_name')['x'].transform('first')
```

Comment: `df['x_diff'] = df.x - df.groupby('main_name')['x'].transform('first')` is precisely what I needed, thank you.

Comment: @Aeroblop - Super, so no negative values? Need positive in output?

Comment: negative was what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 3 steps:

1. Groupby `main_name`
2. For each group: Create a new column (called for ex. x_shifted) that contains the previous value. For that, you can use `df.shift(1)` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)
3. For each group: Create the column `x_diff` that is the difference between `x_shifted` and `x`

Comment: My bad, this will give the diff between consecutive rows, which is not exactly what you are looking for.